# Sign convention for derivatives in a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded space

Tags: derivatives, graded-modules, graded-rings, superalgebra

Suppose $V=V_0\oplus\theta V_1$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded super vector space.

**Note:** Since $\theta^2=0$, this implies $\theta\mathrm{d}\theta=-\mathrm{d}\theta\cdot\theta$.

However, I wish to know if the following equation is correct --
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}-\theta\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta\partial t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The article on [superspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superspace) on Wikipedia has some simple discussions.  Maybe also look at [Supersolutions](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9901094) by Daniel Freed and Pierre Deligne.

---

An arbitrary function on $\mathbb{R}^{1|1}$ is $f(t) + \theta g(t)$ and the operator $\tfrac{d}{d\theta}$ is going to take the 1-st order term in theta, so

$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \big[ f(t) + \theta g(t) \big] = g(t)$$

We can see what happens when we apply your differential operator:

$$ \frac{d}{d\theta} \left( \theta \frac{d}{dt} \right) \big[ f(t) + \theta g(t) \big] = 
\frac{d}{d\theta}  \big[ \theta \frac{df}{dt} \big] = \frac{df}{dt}
$$

Which sign does that correspond to?

Comment: Wouldn't the $\frac{d}{dt}$ term act on $\theta g(t)$?

Comment: @vkarve $\theta \cdot \theta g'(t) = 0$ since $\theta^2 = 0$.  Maybe you also need $\tfrac{d\theta}{dt} = 0$ and are left with $\theta g'(t)$.

Comment: So I cannot simply expand the outer $\frac{d}{d\theta}$ using a Liebnitz rule? No way to arrive at your answer without a test function? (Thanks for your patience. Those sources you quote seem relevant, but unfortunately, I am too unsophisticated to get them.)